# Stopping of quadratic covariaton

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I am given two local martingales $M$ and $N$ and a stopping time $\tau$. We work on a finite time interval $[0,T]$. I want to prove
$$\langle M,N\rangle^{\tau}=\langle M^\tau,N\rangle$$
using the uniqueness of the process $\langle M,N\rangle$ among all continuous, adapted processes of finite variation such that $MN-\langle M,N\rangle$ is a local martingale. (The superscript $\tau$ just indicates the stopped process.)
Can someone give me a hint how I could find a proof? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you know that $$\langle \int_0^{\bullet} f(s) \, dM_s \rangle_t = \int_0^t f(s)^2 \, d\langle M \rangle_s$$ (whenever the expectation of the rhs is finite)?

Comment: The proof of this follows from $\langle M^{\tau}\rangle = \langle M\rangle^{\tau}$ for a local $L^2$ martingale $M$. However, the proof of the latter statement is quite technical. See Lemmas 3.27 and 3.29 in http://www.math.wisc.edu/~seppalai/courses/735/notes.pdf (after you tried hard enough of course :)